# Use css nth-child infinitely

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I need put `margin-right:0px` each 3 divs.

Actually i use this code but because wordpress are crazy, don't work correct in index.php and archive.php:

```
.post {position:relative !important;float:left !important;width:207px !important;margin-right:24px;}
.post:nth-child(4n+0) {margin-right:0px !important;}
```

But only do it in first third div, but not in 6, 9, 12.... Why?

```
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:24px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:24px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:0px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:24px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:24px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:0px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:24px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:24px;
<div class="post"></div> */ margin-right:0px;
```

I have 9 post by page, it's possible put in css specified div:first div.second .... with different css?

I can't use nth-child because don't work correctly in my wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:nth-child(3n)` to target 3rd / 6th /9th etc..

And it works as expected.. perhaps you are not seeing it due to the layout..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/tY2Dh/

---

<strike>**Update (*after updated question*)**</strike>

Your CSS rules target elements with the `category-pro` class assigned.

But your html elements have a `post` class assigned to them.

You need to add the `category-pro` class to those elements, or change your rules to

```
.post{..}
.post:nth-child(3n){...}
```

Comment: don't work in my wordpress, i don't know why. i have 9 post by page, it's possible put in css specified div:first div.second .... with different css?

Comment: @vektor, can you post a link to it ?

Comment: @vektor, also `:nth-child()` will not work on IE8 (*in case you are seeing the problem there..*)

Comment: i'm working in local :( It's my first time in local with XAMPP. one second and edit question

Comment: not, don't work in all browsers, in index.php works with 4n in archive.php don't work. i'm desperated

Comment: @vektor the class on the `div` elements is `post` and your css targets "category-pro". Either change the class in the html, or change the classname in the CSS

Comment: sorry, i'm trying a lot of ways and was my mistake! :)

Comment: @vektor, should they fit in a 3x3 grid ? if so is the container at least 669px wide ?

Comment: because theme works with that. but if 1 and 2 have 23px of right margin and 3 have 0px, works fine in all browsers

Comment: @vektor keep in mind that when calculating the size of the divs you need to add borders and paddings as well (*and also their contents should not exceed the 207px*)

Comment: i have in mind all paddings, margins... but there are something wrong in index.php because 3n must will work...

Comment: i close this question and when i have this code online i will ask again. thanks to all. great people here